# Updating the values of variables in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a relatively simple script for manipulating the text in two fields. This works great initially but when I click on the button `#check` the values of `$field1` and `$field2` don't seem to update. This means that whilst the script can manipulate the second field when text is inputted in the first field, it cannot manipulate the first field when text is inputted in the second field.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var val = "";
    $field1 = $("#password");
    $field2 = $("#fake-password");

    $('#check').click(function() {
        $field1 = $("#fake-password");
        $field2 = $("#password");
        $("#password").hide();
        $('#check').hide();
        $("#fake-password").show().focus();
        $('#check-inv').show();
    });

    $('#check-inv').click(function() {
        $field1 = $("#password");
        $field2 = $("#fake-password");
        $("#fake-password").hide();
        $('#check-inv').hide();
        $("#password").show().focus();
        $('#check').show();
    });

    $(function () {
        $field1.on('keydown', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $field2.html($field1.val());
                val = $field1.val();
                $field2.val(val);
            }, 0);
        });
    });
});
```

I apologise if this is an obvious mistake as I am relatively new to the language but I would appreciate any help in fixing this problem.

Comment: Side note: You're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicti Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html): Declare `$field1` and `$field2`.

Comment: The variables should be declared with "var". To have access to them in different functions you should declare them outside of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code runs immediately on `ready`:

```
$(function () {
    $field1.on('keydown', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $field2.html($field1.val());
            val = $field1.val();
            $field2.val(val);
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

It uses the **then-current** value of `$field1`, and so hooks the event on the `#password` field.

Your best bet is probably to hook the event to *both* fields; within the handler body, the value of `$field1` and `$field2` as of when the event runs will be as you expect. So:

```
$field1.add($field2).on('keydown', function () {
```

---

Also note that `$(function() { })` is a shortcut for hooking up a `ready` handler. Since that code is already inside a `ready` handler, there's no need to wrap it *again*.

Combining that with the suggestion above (and declaring `$field1` and `$field2` so we don't fall prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)), we get (see `**` comments):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var val = "";
    var $field1 = $("#password");                     // **
    var $field2 = $("#fake-password");                // **

    $('#check').click(function() {
        $field1 = $("#fake-password");
        $field2 = $("#password");
        $("#password").hide();
        $('#check').hide();
        $("#fake-password").show().focus();
        $('#check-inv').show();
    });

    $('#check-inv').click(function() {
        $field1 = $("#password");
        $field2 = $("#fake-password");
        $("#fake-password").hide();
        $('#check-inv').hide();
        $("#password").show().focus();
        $('#check').show();
    });

    // ** Note no $(function() { }) wrapper:
    $field1.add($field2).on('keydown', function () {  // **
        setTimeout(function () {
            $field2.html($field1.val());
            val = $field1.val();
            $field2.val(val);
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: It should also be noted that with the release of jQuery 3.0 the `$(document).ready(fn)` form of the ready handler has been [deprecated in favor of the `$(fn)` form](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#deprecated-document-ready-handlers-other-than-jquery-function). I don't see them getting rid of `.ready` anytime soon but who knows what will happen by time 4.0 comes out.